# What is the best index for this SQL query?

Tags: sql, indexing

What is the best index and composite indexes for this kind of SQL query? It is taking 8 seconds for an 7.075.164 lines table with solos index for ID, Data, Relatorio, cat, Atributo2, Pais.

```
SELECT c.ID as cat, Data, Relatorio, SUM(X), SUM(Y), Atributo2 
     FROM table a
     INNER JOIN categorias c ON c.ID = a.Atributo
        WHERE (Atributo2 = '' OR Relatorio IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')) AND Pais = '1' AND Relatorio != 'ddd' AND NaoContar = 0
     GROUP BY Data, Relatorio, cat, Atributo2
```

Comment: Qualify your column names so other people know what the query is doing.

Comment: And indexes depend greatly on data size in table and if this table is used anywhere else.  You can create an index for this query but it could slow down everything else if the table is used elsewhere with different criteria on it.